# Global functions in Multi-File projects?

Tags: c++, c++11

I am very new to programming and having a bit of an issue. I have created a simple purchasing program as a university assignment. One of the tasks of the assignment is to use separate files for each of the three classes that I have created. The problem lies here, at least one of these classes methods use global functions that are also used by the main. When I try to migrate the classes and class methods to separate files, a duplication error is given. Is there any way I can get around this?

Example

a.h //header for class a

```
class A 
{
void example1(); //global function used in class a
};
//end of class header
```

a.cpp

```
void a::example1() 
{
example(); //global function used in both class a and main
}
//end of class cpp
```

program.cpp

```
void example() //global function used in both class a and main
{
//do something
}

int main()
{
example(); //global function used in main
}
```

Comment: Please create a [MCVE] so we can help you.

Answer (score 4):

Put the function declarations in a header file, and the corresponding function definition in a .cpp file:

**lib.h:**

```
#ifndef H_LIB
#define H_LIB

void foo();  // declaration

#endif
```

**lib.cpp:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "lib.h"

// definition
void foo()
{
    std::cout << "foo() called\n";
}
```

**main.cpp:**

```
#include "lib.h"

int main()
{
    foo();   // use
}
```

**Compilation:**

```
g++ -W -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -std=c++14 lib.cpp main.cpp -o prog
```

Comment: I tried this, but it gives me an error saying that each of the global functions are already defined

Comment: Oh My God, I am a moron. The entire time i didn't notice i had the library declaration in the class header twice...

Thanks for all your help :)